# How to access current object textures/uvs in scene.overrideMaterial?

Tags: three.js

I want to make BokehPass to work with transparent objects. I see that I could replace materialDepth with my own material, but I do not see how would I pass proper texture there. Is it even possible? Is it possible with the engine hack?

Comment: Have a `MeshBasicMaterial` with a texture as `scene.overrideMaterial` doesn't work?

Comment: I have multiple materials (

Comment: I ended up changing BokehPass to overwrite/restore materials in meshes instead of using scene.overrideMaterial, in case anyone is reading here.